# Ember data : createObject with an initial async relationship value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've been using ember and ember data for a few months and I am now working on optimisations of my webapp.

I have this `feed` model :

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  app: DS.belongsTo('app', {async:true}),
  icon: DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  typeName: DS.attr('string'),
  rootElement: DS.belongsTo('element', {async:true}),
  position: DS.attr('number'),
  fontAwesomeIcon:DS.attr('string'),

  htmlId:function () {
    return "module_"+this.get('id');
  }.property(),
});
```

When I am trying to create a new `feed` object I only need to specify my backend an app and a type so I do this :

```
addFeed: function() {
    var app=this.get('model');
    var selectTypeForm = document.getElementById('selectFeedType');
    var type = selectTypeForm.options[selectTypeForm.selectedIndex].value
    var newFeed = this.store.createRecord('feed', {
        app:this.get('model'),
        typeName:
    });          
    newFeed.save();
},
```

My problem is that if the `app` property is async (like in this example) the app id is never sent to my backend on the POST request (it's like I never set it). 
If I switch it to `async:false` in the feed model, it accepts my app id at creation and correctly sends it to my backend.

Is it impossible to write an async property ?

Thanks

Versions : `Ember 1.7.0` and `Ember data  1.0.0-beta.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Data had that bug for quite a long time, but it was fixed in Ember data 1.0.0-beta.11 for creation.  Setting an async property was fixed in beta.12.  Your easiest route is to upgrade.

Comment: Sweet, I upgraded to the beta 11 and it worked for the creation. I couldn't chose the beta 12 since it's not available via bower, it must be a canary build. I only need to set those during creation for now so I can wait for the release of beta 12 in production. Thanks for the help!